# How can I make IntelliJ/PyCharm be able to correctly identify every part of a Python namespace?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I use many python packages sharing a namespace (setuptools has support for that). Those work well with python 2.7 with setuptools. My question is regarding the PyCharm plugin for IntelliJ: it does not fully recognize the files and members of the package.

Assume I have many packages:

First package:

```
cantrips
+--- types
|    +--- ...
+--- patterns
|    +--- ...
+--- (more subpackages here)
+--- entropy.py
+--- (more *.py files here)
```

Second package:

```
cantrips
+--- watch
     +--- ...
```

If I try to import anything inside `cantrips.watch` or `cantrips.entropy` I have no problem at all (this works perfectly in Python27). **However** the Pycharm plugin in IntelliJ IDEA 13 does not seem to be able to find `cantrips.entropy` with code inspection.

**Q**: How can I correctly make IntelliJ/PyCharm understand every part of the namespace?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using PyCharm 2019.1 and I've found a way to do it (It may qualify for a workaround)

The trick with namespace packages is that, one package is distributed over multiple directories, once you understand this fact, it's pretty easy.

Typically with PyCharm, the Content Root Directory or Project Root Directory is set to the directory you opened the project in (Default of Normal Packages), as it does not expect a namespace package. This confuses PyCharm as it sets the structure accordingly for the interpreter to set the PYTHONPATH.

To correct this for Namespace packages, just add all the directories that have the namespace folder to the Content Root.

```
File -> Settings -> Project Structure -> Add Content Root
```

So if you had a structure as

```
rootdir/
+--dist_package1/
   +--namespace/
      +--file1.py
+--dist_package2/
   +--namespace/
      +--file2.py
```

Instead of setting "Content Root" directory as `rootdir`, set it to all the directories that contain the `namespace`, such as, `dist_package1` and `dist_package2`.

Remove the original Content Root that was set to `rootdir`.

This should fix the unresolved references to the namespace package

**UPDATE (07/25/2019):**

Instead doing it the difficult way, you could just right-click on `dist_package1` and `dist_package2` and select

```
Mark Directory As -> Sources Root
```

This should resolve your imports

Answer (score 2):

Are the packages in separate projects?

I think I am having the same issue and have filed a support ticket with JetBrains.

If in the second package you can import cantrips.entropy but in the body of the code if the code inspection can't resolve cantrips.entropy such as:

```
import cantrips.entropty

def my_func():
    cantrips.entropy.do_stuff()
    ...
```

The IDE complains that "entropy" is not resolved in my_func by highlighting it in yellow.

A couple of work-arounds are to use an alais:

```
import cantrips.entropty as cantrips_entropty

def my_func():
    cantrips_entropy.do_stuff()
    ...
```

Or use the "from import" syntax:

```
from cantrips.entropty import do_stuff

def my_func():
    do_stuff()
    ...
```

Hope this helps

Comment: My support request has been turned into a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16688

Comment: They fail as you say, in your case. But there's also the case where namespaced packages are installed in my -say- virtualenv or global python path. Packages there are NEVER resolved if namespaced.

Comment: Try installing such packages in your pythonpath (either global or venv) and remove them as projects: IntelliJ will fail to detect them entirely (not just all-but-the-last).

Comment: A workaround that i use is to create pycharm projects for the other namespace package roots and attach those project in the same pycharm session.